# HTTP Post via Android-Java does not work

Tags: java, php, android

I 'm using the following code to post value variables to a server:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


try{

    URL url= new URL(params[0]);
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection= (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
    OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter= new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
    String post_data= URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(params[1], "UTF-8");
    post_data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(params[2], "UTF-8");
    bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
    bufferedWriter.flush();
    bufferedWriter.close();
    outputStream.close();

}catch (MalformedURLException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
```

}

Here is the async-task call:

```
 BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker= new BackgroundWorker(this);
 backgroundWorker.execute("http://...", "somename", "somesurname");
```

The code runs fine (no errors), however I'm not able to see any data in my database (.php is also working correctly-double checked).

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using volley instead, here's a good and easy tutorial: http://www.itsalif.info/content/android-volley-tutorial-http-get-post-put

But here is how I used httpURLConnection:

```
public String executePost() {
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        //Create connection
        url = new URL(/*URL HERE*/);

    String urlParameters = "/*THE PARAMS. YOU KNOW THIS ;) */";

    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" +
            Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");

    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);

    //Send request
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
            connection.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    //Get Response
    InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(line);
        response.append('\r');
    }
    rd.close();
    return response.toString();

} catch (Exception e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;

} finally {

    if (connection != null) {
        connection.disconnect();
    }
}
}
```